# Simulate user input (keyboard, mouse) in Java?

Tags: java, key, mouse, simulate

Is there a way to simulate key strokes in java? For example:

I start *k.jar*, and after

```
Thread.wait(10000);
```

without pressing any keys, the program will simulate that the user is typing.

I'm also interested in mouse movement and clic simulation.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for "Java Robot AWT"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), which is a built-in class that facilitates automated keyboard/mouse interaction.

It can fire mouse and keyboard actions, and get information about pixels on the screen.